# postgresql - could not determine polymorphic type because input has type "unknown"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to write a function that checks if an expression is true or not, the function has in total three parameters. The first parameter is the expression, for example 1<5 which would be true.

The second and third parameters let the function know what to return if this statement is true :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION iff( expression boolean ,true_type anyelement , false_type anyelement ) 
RETURNS anyelement AS 
$$ 
DECLARE 
BEGIN
    IF expression = TRUE THEN
        RETURN true_type;
    ELSEIF expression = FALSE THEN
        RETURN false_type;
    END IF;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The function works for integer values, boolean but not for string literals.

Example:
This statement works and returns 2.

```
SELECT IFF(false,1,2);
```

Example 2:
This statement doesnt work and gives the following error message:
could not determine polymorphic type because input has type "unknown"

```
SELECT IFF(false,'','');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string literal in PostgreSQL has type `unknown`.

You can solve the problem by explicitly casting to the desired type:

```
SELECT iff(false, ''::text, '');
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand now.